# mod_expires, exclude a single directory

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

is it possible to exclude one or more directorys from `mod_expires` with the `expires.conf` ?

I know how to make a setup for `file` and `mime`-types, but I'm lost to tell it not to add expire headers to files from a specific directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with the Directory parameter.

```
<Directory /your/directory>
    ExpiresActive Off 
</Directory>
```